# How to display all products for one perticular category?

Tags: magento

I am facing a problem that I am having 3 categories like... 1)A, 2)B and 3)C. Now as per the settings in admin, each category's product listing having pagination but I don't want pagination dependent listing in category B. Instead I want to display all it's products on one single page.

What should be done for this?

Any Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit the category in the Magento Admin UI. Find the 'Custom Design' tab and the 'Custom Layout' text area in that tab. Add the following:

```
<reference name="product_list_toolbar_pager">
    <action method="addPagerLimit" translate="label">
        <mode>list</mode>
        <limit>all</limit>
        <label>All</label>
    </action>
    <action method="setDefaultListPerPage">
        <limit>all</limit>
    </action>
</reference>
```

**NB**: This still leaves the pager toolbar for the customer to limit the display and/or sort the results.

Comment: Thanks very much Lee Saferite. Now what i desired is coming. Thank you again.